DataFrame interpolation yielding unexpected values for adjacent indeces
I'm trying to interpolate a simple DataFrame.
I need to make an interpolation over the column "col" using the column "PRICE". Then I need to fill its nan values.
Here's what I'm doing with a sample data:
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Sample data setup
data = {
    "PRICE": [4000, 3999.99, 3999.9, 3999.9],
    "col": [16.9, np.nan, 16.9, 26.6]
}
df_pivot = pd.DataFrame(data)

df_pivot["col"] = df_pivot.set_index("PRICE").interpolate(method='index').reset_index(drop=True).loc[:, "col"]
df_pivot

The result is this:
  PRICE   col
4000.00 16.90
3999.99 17.87
3999.90 16.90
3999.90 26.60

Which is wrong for the second index, as I expect a linear interpolation and thus this simple linear formula:
y(xo)= y1 + (y2-y1)(xo - x1)/(y2 - y1)
Therefore, I expect the second value to be 16.90.
What could I be doing wrong and how could I fix this?
I also need this method to work the other way around: So if the data is flipped, the solution yields the same expected behaviour.

When I change method='index' to method='nearest', I get your desired output.

Please edit the title. It is working (i.e. not raising an error), but it's not getting the result you were expecting. For tips on writing a good title, see [ask] and/or How do I write a good title?.

For the title, I meant something even more specific, like "Why is interpolation putting a totally different value when the two adjacent values are the same?"

You have a typo in the formula: y2 - y1 should be x2 - x1

It is doing linear interpolation, but since the index isn't sorted ascending, the values it's using aren't the ones you expected. If you sort the index, you can see the problem:
df_pivot.set_index('PRICE')['col'].sort_index(kind='stable')

PRICE
3999.90    16.9
3999.90    26.6
3999.99     NaN
4000.00    16.9
Name: col, dtype: float64

You can see it's interpolating between 26.6 and 16.9 (y1 and y2) relative to 3999.90 and 4000.00 (x1 and x2) at 3999.99 (x).

To fix it, where the index is already monotonic but in the wrong direction, you could "flip" the index by subtracting from the max.
(
    df_pivot.set_index('PRICE')['col']
    .pipe(lambda df: df.set_axis(df.index.max() - df.index))
    .interpolate(method='index')
)

PRICE
0.00    16.9
0.01    16.9
0.10    16.9
0.10    26.6
Name: col, dtype: float64

This makes the index monotonic increasing (i.e. sorted ascending) instead of monotonic decreasing (i.e. sorted descending).

If you want to allow indexes in either order, you could check if it's monotonic, e.g.:
if df_pivot['PRICE'].is_monotonic_decreasing:
    # flip
    ...
elif df_pivot['PRICE'].is_monotonic_increasing:
    # proceed as normal
    ...
else:
    # sort? error? I'll leave this up to you
    ...


P.S. I think the problem is obvious, but LMK if you don't get it and I'll explain

Yes, could you elaborate please?

@NicolásRivera I just tried writing something up, but I got stuck cause it's not clear why you were expecting what you were. This is related to the comment I left about the title. Could you edit the question to clarify?

Done. Your approach didn't work for another case that I encountered with another data. In this case the quantities were ordered in descending order. Would you suggest a solution that works for both cases? (I have added this comment at the end)
